# How can I put in device settings options to grant access to camera and photo library in Xamarin Forms iOS project

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, privacy

I'm working on Xamarin forms application and for the iOS project I need to an entry for the application in the device settings with two option in order to user can grant access to device camera and photo library.
How can I do that?

PS: I tried with Privacy options in the info.plist file but this not create an entry in device settings for my application.
[Info.plist entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD6Yh.png)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Are you having issues adding key/values to the Info.plist or are you trying to add settings options in device settings for your App?

Comment: As I understood, he has issue adding Camera/Photo library in Settings page. With Settings.bundle and Info.plist (provided in picture), seems that is not appear in iOS Settings page

Comment: you generally **request** permissions as they are needed at runtime, and the user can grand or deny them.  Users can then modify their selections in the Settings app.

Comment: He said that the Camera and Photo Library does not appear in Settings page when app is installed. Do they appear after confirming/denied first time dialog regarding Camera/Photo Library ?